# Way ahead in learning octopus Deployment

Tags: deployment, devops, octopus-deploy

I am totally new to Octopus Deployment and I am struggling to find a starting point

What is the best pathway to take to understand the basic fundamentals of octopus deployment ?

Are there any pre-requisites ?

Amy recommended courses/books that I can take ?

Comment: [Octopus docs](https://octopus.com/docs/overview) should provide you a good start

Comment: Try our Getting Started webinar: https://youtu.be/Vpuyr_WTamU 

We run these pretty regularly: https://octopus.com/events

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation as yourself. I had zero training and was thrown in at the deep end.

I would suggest you start with a simple application and get your head around the 'process' steps required to deploy your application. For example, A simple site may have the following steps:

1. Stop the app pool and site in IIS
2. Deploy the site to IIS
3. Execute any SQL scripts
4. Start the app pool and site in IIS

There are a number of built-in steps that can help with this. I suggest you have a look through them.

You then want to look at the 'variables' required for each environment. Again, for example, you may have a variable for the website hostname with values such as:

1. DEV = website-dev
2. UAT = website-uat
3. QA = website-qa
4. LIVE - website-live

When deploying the app to different enivorments, a different set of variables will be used.

Have a look at the Octopus youtube page for some good resources:

[Octopus youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCURDSDCwx9ZiCMcLdc8d6Uw/playlists)

I found Octopus easy to pick up simply by trial and error.

Good luck!